# How to transform a SAS log with array function and temporary columns into SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS Logic containing temporary columns (Code et Codep) and an array function and this code I do not understand much , I wanted to translate this SAS Logic in sql server from a SELECT on the table SEL which is already existing, someone can help me to translate this SAS logic in SQL Server, I am blocked

```
%let YEAR=2023;

%macro SORTIES(dat_obs);
proc sort data=SEL_MFCFINAN out=SEL; by exer_sin num_sin num_vic descending dat_oper descending num_mvt; run;

data SEL;
    set SEL;
    by exer_sin num_sin num_vic descending dat_oper descending num_mvt;
    array code(%eval(&YEAR-2013+1));
    array codep(%eval(&YEAR-2013+1));
    retain code codep;
    format Date ddmmyy10.;
    if first.num_vic then do;
        do i=1 to %eval(&YEAR-2013+1);
            code(i)='0';
            codep(i)='0';
        end;
    end;
    %do j=&YEAR %to 2013 %by -1;
        Date="31DEC&j"d;
        if dat_oper<=Date and code(%eval(&j-2013+1))='0' then do;
            code(%eval(&j-2013+1))='1';
            sit='F';
            output;
        end;
    %end;
    drop code1--code%eval(&YEAR-2013+1) codep1--codep%eval(&YEAR-2013+1) i;

run;
%mend SORTIES;
%SORTIES;
```

Comment: Don't you have any documentation or comments in the code that explain WHY they are running that SAS code?    At a minimum your show show example input and the output for that input.  Also show what you have tried so far and explain in what way it did not work.

Comment: I Will try to explain the code tomorow in université

Comment: That last loop, where you're generating one record per year is going to be hard to do in SQL. You'll need to use cursor logic most likely as you're creating new rows and SQL typically doesn't do that easily.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to output one row per year when a exer_sin num_sin num_vic combination has at least one operational date in that year.

Something like this

```
create table want as
select exer_sin, num_sin, num_vic, year(oper_dat) as year, 'F' as sit
from have
group by exer_sin, num_sin, num_vic, year(oper_dat)
having count(dat_oper) > 0
```